# Angularjs ui-router in html5 enabled mode not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Angularjs version **1.3.14**, ui-router version **0.2.15**, html5mode **enabled**. When I try **http://localhost/firsttime** it redirects to **http://localhost**  as fallback

Here is **app.js**

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('tt', [
  'ngRoute',
  'tt.home',
  'tt.firsttime',
  'ui.router'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // Routes
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    // set HTML5 history API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Here is **firsttime.js**

```
// create our angular app and inject ngAnimate and ui-router 
// =============================================================================
angular.module('tt.firsttime', ['ui.router'])

// configuring our routes 
// =============================================================================
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$routeProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $routeProvider) {
    // catch all route
    // send users to the form page 
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/firsttime');

    $stateProvider
        // route to show our basic form (/firsttime)
        .state('firsttime', {
            url: '/firsttime',
            templateUrl: 'firsttime/form.html',
            //controller: 'formController'
        })
}])

// our controller for the form
// =============================================================================
.controller('formController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log('FORM controller');
}]);
```

And here is **form.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

  <div id="form-container">

      <div class="page-header text-center">
          <h2>Let's Be Friends</h2>

          <!-- the links to our nested states using relative paths -->
          <!-- add the active class if the state matches our ui-sref -->
          <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
              <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="firsttime.profile"><span>1</span> Profile</a>
              <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="firsttime.interests"><span>2</span> Interests</a>
              <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="firsttime.payment"><span>3</span> Payment</a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- use ng-submit to catch the form submission and use our Angular function -->
      <form id="signup-form" ng-submit="processForm()">
          <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
          <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
      </form>

  </div>



</div>
</div>
```

**Update** Here is the nginx routing block

```
    location / {
        root   html/app;
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `config` block from the `app.js` that may conflicting with your current route system. You should never use both routing engine together. By looking at your code it seems like you are trying to use `ui-router` for routing. So by removing `app.js` config block will potentially solve your issue.

The issue is because of this line

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

After removing code from the `app.js` you should move below lines to `firsttime.js` config block, this will enable the `html5mode`

```
// set HTML5 history API
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: Had tried, no luck! Has it something to do with nginx config? Updated orig post

Comment: @Dewsworld that the issue you need to fix on nginx side.. I;m not familliar with it.. Sorry

Comment: I believe the error was due to mixing routeprovider and stateprovider. Upgraded to ui-router, since it looks more promising than ngRoute

Comment: @Dewsworld that what I suggested in my answer.. you are using `ui-router` remove the `ngRoute` thing thoroughly

Comment: @Dewsworld Glad to help you..Thanks :)